# Add external jar in gradle to Android project

Tags: android, jar, gradle

I am trying to add a jar to a project on Android. I did a test with the maps.jar library. Which has a class named com.google.android.maps.MapView when i do the import of that class. I get the error package com.google.android.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

I try to include this jar file in several ways into my gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
 runtime files('/Users/user/Documents/workspace/MyAndroidApp/libs/maps.jar')  
 //runtime fileTree(dir: '/Users/user/Documents/workspace/MyAndroidApp/libs', include: '*.jar')
 //classpath fileTree(dir: '/Users/user/Documents/workspace/MyAndroidApp/libs', include: 'maps.jar')        
}
```

Not luck so far.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: As the description from android tool site: > The compile configuration is used to compile the main application. Everything in it is added to the compilation classpath and also packaged in the final APK. It seems that it will package all maps class into APK. Is that ok?
Any idea if we just need runtime reference not static reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile dependencies have to be added to the `compile` configuration (not `runtime` or `class path`).

Comment: One more question. If I put the .class files under the folder maps can I include it as compile files('/Users/ddayer/Documents/workspace/MyAndroidApp/libs/maps/*') ? cause is not working when I try to use a class on my java project.

Comment: A class path can contain references to individual archives and directories holding class files. Hence `files("/Users/ddayer/Documents/workspace/MyAndroidApp/libs/maps")` should work. In cases where you need wildcards, you'll have to use `fileTree` as you already did above.

Comment: Well I dont know if is the android plugin for android, but when I try to add the classes in that plain way it doesnt found them. I need to create a jar file first.

Comment: Yes, probably something Android-specific then.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how i got it going:

1. Drag your jar file into the libs folder.
2. Right click on the jar file and select "Add Library" now the jar
   file is a library.
3. open the `build.gradle` file (note there are two `build.gradle` files at least, dont use the root one use the one in your project scope).
4. find the dependencies section (for me i was trying to the admob
   -GoogleAdMobAdsSdk jar file)

   `dependencies {
           compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar','libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1.jar')
       }`
5. last go into `settings.gradle` and ensure it looks something like
   this:

   `include ':yourproject', ':yourproject:libs:GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1'`
6. Finally, Go to Build--->Rebuild Project